# Enter passphrase for key /.ssh/id_rsa' after push

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh

I spent a lot of time with git well and once, when I push my commit - I had: enter passphrase for key /.ssh/id_rsa' . Read a lot about solution of it but finally can't find correct answer.
[image]
Does anybody know how to fix it and what happens?

Comment: What is the url of the remote git repo  origin to which you are pushing? And if it is an ssh one, did you published your public jey on that server first? (as on GitHub, for instance: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-3-add-your-ssh-key-to-github)

Comment: This might be a better canonical: [Git enter long passphrase for every push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106137/git-enter-long-passphrase-for-every-push).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have set passphrase for you ssh-key:

```
demas@ubuntu:/mnt/coursera$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/demas/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/demas/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
```

Comment: I entered pasword and have next - permission denied (publickey) fatal: Could not read from remote repository. please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.My problem is probably something else

Comment: Is it Github repository or your own git-server ?

Comment: Output of 'git remote -v' will be usefull

Comment: yes on my own, okey will try

Comment: 1. Do you deploy your public ssh key to remote server ? 2. The user on remote server (you can find it on the output of 'git remote -v' command) must have permissions to read/write to repository folder. 3. Check the repository folder (you can find it on the output of 'git remote -v' command) exists on the remote server.

Comment: If you recreated your ssh key (using command ssh-keygen), you need to deploy the new version of the key on the remore server.

Comment: @EvaNebko if you enter a passphrase for your private key, you need to use `ssh-agent` too. See [Could not open a connection to your authentication agent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17846529/456814).

Comment: @demas oh, my brain is broken!)

solution - just removed old ssh key from local repo -> create new -> add ro the repo.
Tnx all for help