# Git push error with Husky

Tags: git, git-husky

[image]

I'm using Windows with git bash, and yesterday i did a commit with other scripts and nothing happened. Today I can't push my files on account this error above. Anyone knows why this happening?

Comment: You have to enter your login data. There is no error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enter passphrase for key /.ssh/id\_rsa' after push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588432/enter-passphrase-for-key-ssh-id-rsa-after-push)

Comment: I solved, it was a comment line who impossibilited the push