# Avoid prompting password for git commands in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, passwords, required

I have set up ssh in my ubuntu server which I have installed git.
So, I append my pubic key to the 
~/.ssh/authorized_keys file of the server which git is installed.
I can use any git commands from my local pc(where my public key is pasted in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys)

Yet, I just wanted to know how do I avoid entering the password each time I use a git command.
So that I can avoid entering the password each time.
Thanks

Comment: Is you ssh key protected by a passphrase?

Answer (score 0):

Response from https://askubuntu.com/questions/362280/enter-ssh-passphrase-once

> Update: seems to be a bug from 13.10:
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpam-ssh/+bug/1247169
>
> Anyway running the following commands the problem was fixed for me:
>   **How to fix**
>
> I fixed this by entering the following commands:
>
> $ ssh-agent bash
>
> This creates a new bash process that allows you to add private keys.
>   When adding a new private key you will be prompted for the passphrase
>   once and only once.
>
> And then:
>
> ```
> $ ssh-add /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa:  Identity added:
> ```
>
> /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa)
>
> ...where username is your username. You can do the same using $USER
>   variable:
>
> ```
> $ ssh-add /home/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa
> ```
>
> And the problem was fixed.

Duplicate:

[Git enter long passphrase for every push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106137/git-enter-long-passphrase-for-every-push)

[Git keeps asking me for my ssh key passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032461/git-keeps-to-ask-me-for-ssh-key-passphrase)

**EDIT**

The only way I know is to use something using `expect`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no host.example.com
expect -exact "Password: "
send -- "secret\r"
expect {\$\s*} { interact }
```

and probably deal with [ssh-config's ProxyCommand](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh_config%205) or use [python version](https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password) which is more complex and allow keeping credentials in config file.

And as a note - the only acceptable solution (secure and convenient) is ssh keys based auth.

Comment: Hi,
This is not the passphrase of my public key, to be specific I am stating the details again
The name of the remote server is rashendra/and the ip is 192.168.1.4
and my local pc is janaka and the 192.168.1.7
and I have clone a git project as project, 
so when I use the following command it requires the password of the remote pc( which is git is installed)
janaka@janaka:~/IdeaProject/project/project$ git pull origin master
rashendra@192.168.1.4's password:
how to avoid this